# Vue.js Error in render: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" - for a table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm using Vue in Laravel. I'm trying to generate a table based on 2 arrays except I'm getting the error in Vue: "Error in render: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". The data is getting passed as I see it in the Vue DevTools.

vue template:

```
<template>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="table-pay">
        <thead>
            <tr role="row">
                <th>ID</th>                        
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <th>City, State</th>
                <th>Age Group</th>
                <th>Payment Time</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template v-for="attendee in attendees">
                <template v-for="pmt in data">
                    <tr role="row" v-if="attendee.id == pmt.user_id">
                        <td>{{ attendee.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ attendee.first_name }} {{ attendee.last_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ attendee.email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ attendee.city }}, {{ attendee.state }}</td>
                        <td>{{ pmt.agegroup }}</td>
                        <td v-if="pmt.agegroup == 'High School'">HS</td>
                        <td v-else-if="pmt.agegroup == 'College'">COL</td>
                        <td v-else="pmt.agegroup == 'JNF'">JNF</td>
                        <td>{{ pmt.payment_time }}</td>
                        <td><a :href="'/admin/invoice/' + attendee.id">View Invoice</a></td>
                        <td>Unregister TODO</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['data', 'attendees']
    }
</script>
```

blade template:

```
<convention-payments :attendees="{{$users}}" :data="{{$vue_data}}"></convention-payments>
```

Here are the database queries... if anyone else has a better ideas well of doing them:

```
// gets payment info of attendees
$attendee_ids = $convDB->table('user_details')->where('registered', '=', '1')->orderBy('user_id', 'asc')->pluck('user_id');        
$users = $db->table('users')->whereIn('id', $attendee_ids)->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'city', 'state')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
$vue_data = $convDB->table('user_payment')->whereIn('user_id', $attendee_ids)->select('user_id', 'agegroup', 'payment_time')->orderBy('user_id', 'asc')->get();

return view('convention.admin.income', ['users' => $users, 'vue_data' => $vue_data]);
```

Essentially, I need to output the payment information for an event with some user demographics info. The 'users' database is on server 1 and the 'event-specific info' database is on server 2.

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this... but I was just going to pull the user IDs from the table on server 2 that notes whether they are registered or not. And then use that information to pull the info from the users database on server 1 as well as their payment info from server 2.

Comment: how many records you have in your database?

Comment: Each array has 357 rows/entries and that number will increase to about 750 once registration is closed

Comment: with your implementation 357* 357 = 133,875 total entries. use limit and pagination

Comment: Is there any better way to query the data? To perhaps combine into one array?

Comment: Is it possible that some infinite loop or a weird naming conflict thing is happening?

Comment: So if I use a regular foreach loop in the blade template things work. However why doesn’t it fit in vue?

Comment: Vue.Js depends on web browser and your blade depends on server they both have different stack.